# Alternative to generic inherited class to constraint an inherited property to be a child of its base type itself

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I want to restrain a member of an inherited class to a specific type. I know I could do it with generic class, but it seems more complicated than it should be.
So, here's an exemple.

```
public class Shape
{
    public Texture texture { get; set; }
}

public class Texture { ... }
public class SpecficTexture : Texture { ... }

public class SpecificShape : Shape
{
    public SpecificShape()
    {
        texture = new SpecficTexture();
    }
}
```

Essentially, in my case I need to implement the class SpecificShape. It's all good but the texture property inside SpecificShape is not known as a specific texture. From the SpecificShape, it need to be known as such. Obviously, I could have the following classes instead.

```
public class Shape2<T> where T : Texture
{
    public T texture { get; set; }
}

public class SpecifShape2 : Shape2<SpecficTexture> { ... }
```

I see two solutions to my problem. Either I go to my team to switch to make Shape a generic class or I cast texture to SpecificTexture whenever I need it. Is there any other way?

I don't like the idea of casting, it doesn't seem elegant to me, and I'm worried about performance issue if I had to do it multiple times. At the same time, I'm not sure it's justified to change back what was already implemented.

Comment: *I don't like the idea of casting, it doesn't seem elegant to me, and I'm worried about performance issue if I had to do it multiple times*. Your problems reside in those two misguided preconceptions, not in the code you wrote.

Comment: The cast you are trying to avoid is called a *reference conversion*, which is dirt cheap, so don't even start worrying about it unless you have empirical data that shows you have a performance issue due to the amount of conversions in your code. Also, avoid any "inner" casts inside you class, don't use autoproperties; use a regular property with a private backing field that can be strongly typed to your specific texture.

Comment: And last, concerning *It's all good but the texture property inside SpecificShape is not known as a specific texture. From the SpecificShape, it need to be known as such*. Please explain *why* you need `Texture` to return the specific texture; include in your question code that demonstrates why you need it.

Comment: Casting isn't a performance issue, but that doesn't make it good. The class design should allow that the only type you need to know or care about is the declared type. If you need to explicitly cast the declared type to some other type, that suggests you first need to determine whether it can be cast to that type. That's chaos and a code smell.

Comment: @ScottHannen Casting is not something unelegant or unperformant to the point that it should be avoided *per se*; it all depends on how you are using it. If there is an obvious solution that avoids casting then by all means, use it, hence the last commentary where I ask what  specific scenario has he encountered where he needs the specific type. As the question stands now, its pretty darn hard to figure out what he needs. There is a good reason why return type variance is not supported in overriden methods; because normally its not such a great and useful feature.

Comment: @InBetween I'd never go so far as to say that nothing should ever be cast. But it's usually a sign that something has gone wrong or gotten messy. If a method has been called, we have a method argument of type A, but we need to check if it's really subtype B or C then something is out of place. We want to get compiler errors, not runtime errors. Also, we don't have to write unit tests to verify that something compiles. But if we're doing runtime type checking then that's more unit tests to write. So I'm not saying never, but never should be the goal.

Comment: @ScottHannen Then I guess new features in c# like pattern matching are code smell... `is` and `as` operators should also be avoided then... I find it hard to understand your point of view, implicit and explicit reference conversions are the daily bread in most code bases, I'm not sure I understand the point you are trying to make. But again, senseless use of casting is wrong, I'm not arguing that, but sensible casting is normal and acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `texture` property virtual in the `Shape`, override it in `SpecificShape` and limit the casting to one specific place:

```
public class Shape
{
    public virtual Texture texture { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificShape : Shape
{
    public SpecificTexture specificTexture { get; set; }

    public override Texture texture
    {
        get { return specificTexture; }
        set
        {
            if (value is SpecificTexture specificValue) //this is the only place we have to have a cast
            {
                specificTexture = specificValue;
            }
            else
            {
                //handle error, throw exception, Debug.Assert, or something
            }
        }
    }

    public SpecificShape()
    {
        specificTexture = new SpecificTexture();
    }
}
```

Whenever you need to use SpecificTexture in your SpecificShape class, you can simply use the `specificTexture` property instead of `texture`.

Furthermore, if the parent `Shape` class doesn't really need the `texture` property setter (perhaps, the `texture` property is only set once in the constructor?), then just get rid of the setter, and you can avoid any casts.